# How to have shadows?

Tags: android, layout, actionbarsherlock, shadows

[image]

I was wondering how to get the shadows like the one in the screenshot...
1. Shadow from ActionBAr(ActionBarSherlock)
2. Shadow from Right Panel.

I tried using gradient... but it is not working well...
Please suggest something...

Comment: i think combination of layouts and gradient in **FrameLayout** would do the trick

Comment: make sure your gradient comes at very last inside FrameLayout so its layered above all other views